# Trying to print out fibbonnaci numbers using an array in ruby. What is wrong with this code?

Tags: ruby

```
arr = [1,1]
lst = arr[arr.size-1]
nx_lst = arr[arr.size-2]
nx_num ||= nx_lst + lst
4.times { arr << nx_num }
puts arr
```

For some reason the nx_num variable wont update. Even when arr is 1,1,2 nx_num stays at the value 2 even though it should be 3. Please help.

Comment: What are all those "enter code here"?

Answer (score 0):

You evaluated `nx_num` once outside of and prior to running the loop. Then, during the four iterations in the loop, you never updated `nx_num`. So the same value of `nx_num` is being pushed four times.